# Socket.IO - For each number of clients, generate new room with Unique Name/ID

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I am trying to build a matchmaking system based on Socket.IO. I've set up the server and data is being stored normally into array. Now i'm wondering this:
• When 10 players join the main room ('Queue') which is by default on connection, how can I make a new room with unique id (ie. lobby_982311298_3427834) and put those people in that room.
• For next 10 players, generate a new unique id and put them in that new room.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, which is for 2 people randomly picked from an array, I did it with something like this:

```
function newRoom(user1, user2){
  users.forEach(function(user){
    if(user.name == user1 || user.name == user2){
        io.sockets.connected[user.id].join('room'+i);
    }
});
  rooms.push(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms['room'+i]);
  i++;
}
```

Where `user1` and `user2` are objects with a name and an id (which is the socket.id) properties. the forEach checks the entire `users` array where users are stored.
So instead of 'room'+i you probably want something like `socket.join(roomname)` where `roomname` has a given string value, in your case can be some random number concatenated or the socket.ids of the clients.